# Ripple effect as found on design.google.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I'm trying to replicate the ripple effect found on design.google.com. On click of a link *in the header* it pushes a ripple across the header. I found a tutorial here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/recreating-the-touch-ripple-effect-as-seen-on-google-design--cms-21655 however, this tutorial does not constrain the click events to the links but rather any click event captured in the header.

What I did was give the links in question a class of "rippleeffect" and direct the on js to listen for "clicks" to that class. This does not have the desired affect... or any affect really. If I change the js to listen to "clicks" found in the header class ("mdl-layout__header") it works... just not as desired.

I've uploaded code to jsfiddle.net/thepaperescape/1qmsh7Ld/
and https://github.com/thepaperescape/Ripple

Please help, and thanks!

Comment: I highly suggest you draft up what you are trying to achieve on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) and share the link here, it is the best way to get some help on your problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thepaperescape/1qmsh7Ld/

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you need to jump to link after the effect 
this can be done via jquery/javascript itself adding below code after the effect
You would also need to preventDefault() from preventing the default behaviour
of the anchor link.

Check my [pen](https://codepen.io/thebunny/pen/pbKvQj) i have created the ripple effect using css3 animation & calculated the offset via jquery. Use this attr to jump to anchor link after the effect.

```
 window.location = $(this).attr("href")
```

Comment: Could you please modify my code to demonstrate how your solution meets my desire effect?